# How to disable rendering the view in ActionController TestCase (Rails 3.0.9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testcase, actioncontroller

What's the proper way to disable ActionController::TestCase to actually render the views?
Alternatively, what'd be the way to render the view without the layout in the tests?

Using rr, I've tried 
    stub(@controller).render { "" }

but this broke the assert_template assertions.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I can't really remember anymore. It was probably something along the lines of the view trying to access something set up in a before_filter or something that's only properly initialized in a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem of disabling just layout, while still rendering the main view. With rspec mocks this works for me:

```
@controller.stub(:layout).and_return(false)
```

I've never used rr, but I would imagine the syntax might be as follows:

```
stub(@controller).layout { false }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do this in Rails 6. With the the mocha gem:

```
ActionController::Metal.any_instance.stubs(:process).returns
```

For other versions of Rails, the easiest way to determine the answer is to add `puts caller` to your action and scan the backtrace. Find something that looks easy to stub and try it.

Answer (score 0):

It is by default disabled.

If you want to enable you can:

1) call this in spec_helper:

```
config.render_views
```

2) put this statement inside your controller test class:

```
render_views
```

If you want to disable it, just add a false parameter like:

```
render_views false
```

Reference: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/docs/controller-specs/render-views